# SQL equivalent to python for loop

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I feel there must be a way to accomplish this for loop directly in SQL. Can someone please give some guidance?

```
for x in range(1, numckts + 1, 6):
      alist.append(x)
      alist.append(x + 1)

for val in alist:
    sql = (
        "SELECT VA FROM circuits WHERE pnl_id = "
        + pnlid
        + " AND Num = "
        + str(val)
        + ";"
    )
    rows = cur.execute(sql)
    for row in rows:
        valA = valA + row[0]
```

Comment: Explaining the purpose of this python code would probably help SQL people to come up with an adequate answer.

Comment: OK, the range is a list of circuits that connects to a panel two at a time across three phases. So then every 6 connections two occur. I hope that is clear enough. LMK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.pnlid
, c.Num
, c.VA
from circuits c
  inner join panel p on p.pnlid = c.pnl_id
where (c.Num % 6) in (1, 2)
```

Comment: I'm sorry if it was not understood. I want to go to a 100% sql (no python). The python code I provided  is working code. I just want to go to sqlite and SQL to do the calc.

Comment: I think that's what this does.  But don't you have to call it from something?

Comment: I'll add a SQL-only version to the answer.

Comment: Yes, I will most likely use a trigger.

Comment: I see you're using SQLite.  My answer works in SQL Server.  I think you may just need to change the beginning to `WITH RECURSIVE`.  See https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: Well from what i understand DECLARE is not a valid sqlite command. The numckts is in the database at panelboards.numckts and pnl_id is equal to panelboards.id. Asside from that is the error: recursive reference in a subquery: a. So i think what needs to happen is set a value in a column A, B, or C when the circuit is generated thereby making the value an internal reference that can be iterated... if you follow what i'm saying. Step iterations just seems to be out of reach for sqlite. Doesn't seem that easy for any database from what i'm seeing. Thanks for your held and time in looking at this.

Comment: `WITH RECURSIVE` should work.  It's in the sqlite docs.

Comment: I don't know how you plan to pass your parameter values (numckts and pnlid) into the query.  You probably wouldn't use `DECLARE` anyway, you'll join that to something else in your trigger design.

Comment: Your Python function allowed you to pass a single value for each `numckts` and `pnlid`.  If this data is in a table, I assume there is more than one row.  Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Comment update:  Your Python function allowed you to pass a single value for each `numckts` and `pnlid`.  If this data is in a table named `panelboards`, I assume there is more than one row.  Can you provide sample data?  Sample data for the `circuits` table would also help.

Comment: Working through this, I think I see what's going on.  Is `panelboards.numckts` the count of the circuits on `circuits` with `circuits.pnl_id = panelboards.id`?

Comment: Been out of loop, sorry. So Yes, you got it.

Comment: We kinda got wrapped around the axle thinking the solution would involve iteration or recursion.  It doesn't.  See my revised answer.

Comment: I could provide data. But how would that worok?

Comment: That's awesome my friend. Works great.

Comment: dougp, something maybe you know right off.. so to look at the three phases I add two to each of (1, 2), ie: 3,4 represents phase b, likewise 5,6 should return phase c however only the first item is returned. Any idea?

Comment: The circuit numbers I would expect get from the python you provided would be 1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14, etc.  This is where clear, complete requirements and sample input and output would come in helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `ROW_NUMBER()` [window function](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) in SQLite to count sequentially rows within each `pnl_id`. Then, find the connections after every 6th row (i.e., 7th and 8th) using modulo operator to filter final aggregation.

Please note: you need SQLite version at least 3.25 for window functions which may ship with Python 3.8.x. Check with `sqlite3.sqlite_version`.

```sql
WITH sub_row AS 
   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.pnl_id ORDER BY rowid) AS rn
           , c.pnl_id
           , c.[VA]
           , p. numckts
    FROM circuits c
    INNER JOIN panelboards p
           ON c.pnl_id = p.id)
    , 
     sub_conn AS
   (SELECT rn
           , CASE WHEN rn % 6 IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS conn           
           , pnl_id
           , [VA]
           , numckts
    FROM sub_row
    WHERE rn < numckts + 1)

SELECT pnl_id, SUM(VA) AS sum_VA
FROM sub_conn
WHERE conn = 1
GROUP BY pnl_id
```

Comment: I'm sorry if it was not understood. I want to go to a 100% sql (not python). (The python code I provided is working code.) I just want to go to sqlite and SQL to do the calc. There doesn't seem to be an easy answer.. There seems to be other approaches I'm just amazed there doesn't seem to be a way to iterate by a step other than 1 in SQLite.

Comment: See revamped SQL only answer. You will need a version of SQLite 3.25+ in order to use window functions. I used info from your above comments. Hopefully it works for your needs.

Comment: This looks interesting. I pasted it into SQLite Studio and it gave an error: syntax at "OVER(" Need some time to look at it a bit closer.

Comment: Check your SQLite version if it supports [window functions](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html), should be 3.25+.